# Problema em quebrar uma String

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, string

Tenho uma string que é concatenada dentro de um *loop*, queria que para cada *loop* fosse criado uma nova linha com os valores concatenados.

Segue o código que estou usando:

```
mensagem ="";

for (int i = 0; i < titulosReceber.Rows.Count; i++) 
    mensagem += "Titulos: " + (titulosReceber[i].TitId).ToString() +
    "FormaPagto: " + (titulosReceber[i].NomeMeioPagamento).ToString() +
    "Valor: " + (titulosReceber[i].Valor).ToString() + " Dt. Venc: " +
    (titulosReceber[i].dVenc)+"\n" ;

SalvarHistorico("Ação Faturar da Saida, gerado(s) o(s)"+ mensagem,
Historico.enumHistoricoTipo.SAI_Faturar, this.Saida[0].Id, IdOperador );
```

A *string* é concatenada, mas não quebra a linha.

Comment: Onde isto está sendo usado? A quebra de linha está presente sim, não tem como não estar. Mas dependendo de onde for usado, ela não aparecerá, porque `\n` não funciona em todos contextos, como o HTML, por exemplo. Quebra de linha em HTML é `<br />`.

Comment: Vc quer que o `SalvarHistorico` seja chamado a cada iteração?

Comment: Andre, se poder só quebra a string já me ajuda bastante.

Comment: O que @bigown falou está correto, `\n` não funciona em páginas web, vc deverá dá um replace `\n` por `<br />`, deve ter alguns métodos/mecanismo para executar esse *replace*

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringBuilder mensagem = new StringBuilder(); 

for (int i = 0; i < titulosReceber.Rows.Count; i++)
    mensagem.Append(string.Format("<br/><b>Titulos:</b> {0} <b>Forma Pagto: :</b>{1} <b>Valor :</b>{2} <b>Dt. Venc :</b>{3}", titulosReceber[i].TitId, titulosReceber[i].NomeMeioPagamento, titulosReceber[i].Valor, titulosReceber[i].dVenc.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")).ToString());

    SalvarHistorico("Ação Faturar da Saida, gerado(s) o(s)"+ mensagem, Historico.enumHistoricoTipo.SAI_Faturar, this.Saida[0].Id, IdOperador );
```

Answer (score 3):

A quebra de linha está ocorrendo normalmente através do `\n` não tem como não ter segundo este código.

Seu problema está em outro lugar. Quando você vai apresentar esta *string* gerada, você não está vendo o texto quebrar pela forma como o mecanismo que fará a apresentação manipula isto. Ou seja, quando você imprime, o `\n` não fica visível como uma quebra de linha. Como você indica usar o ASP.NET, deve estar tentando mostrar isto em uma página HTML, cuja quebra de linha é representada por `<br />`. Então ou você muda neste código para usar este texto como quebra ou então quando for montar a página converte o `\n` para `<br />`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Onde você está exibindo esta mensagem gerada? Se for em um contexto `HTML`, você pode utilizar `mensagem.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />")` antes de exibir que deve funcionar. Outra opção seria ao invés de colocar o `\n` colocar direto o `<br />`.

Comment: Ola Richard dias, obrigado pela ajuda, já conseguir resolver a questão segue o código.

Comment: Marque uma resposta como correta então